# Function for repetitive Google Slides API 'requests' via PHP

Tags: php, google-slides-api

I am new to Google Slides API using PHP.  I am working on a script to produces slides via my script. If I layout all the 'requests' (i.e. createSlide, createTable, insertText) sequentially in the script, .....I am able to produce the slides in Google.  However, I want to minimize all the requests by using a function, but keep encountering errors:

```json
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid requests[1]: No request set.", "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid requests[1]: No request set.", "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } } %s
```

my test sample code:

```
function createNewSlide($requests,$slide_id) {
        $requests[] = new Google_Service_Slides_Request([
                'createSlide' => [
                'objectId' => $slide_id
                ]
        ]);
     return $requests;
   } 

$requests = [];
$slide_id = 'unique_slide_id_'.rand(1,9999999);
$requests[] = createNewSlide($requests,$slide_id);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Execute the request.
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Slides_BatchUpdatePresentationRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));
try {
  $response = $slidesService->presentations->batchUpdate($created_presentation->presentationId, $batchUpdateRequest);
    print("A new slide was added to the presentation<br>");
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //print($e->getMessageAsString()." \n%s\n");
    print($e->getMessage()." \n%s\n");
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Just to add.  If I add the batchUpdate code in the function, to push the request to Google API, it works that way, but I don't want to run the update every time I call the function. I just want to build the $requests[], then run one batchUpdate

Comment: no experience with google slides but your function returns an array so your final $requests is an array of array instead of an array of google objects. shouldn't your function just return a google object instead?

Comment: Not only does your function return an array – it gets the current state of the array passed in as parameter, then you add a new element to it, and return it. So you’d be creating more and more array elements - copies of the already existing ones - each time.

Comment: What is the point of the `$requests` parameter if you don't use it in `createNewSlide($requests,$slide_id);`?

Comment: Thanks @Aerials.  So yes, my thinking was to build $request[]  within the function, then use batchUpdate outside the function to send the slide requests to the Google Slide API. So I send $requests to the function as a way of using the global scope of the parameter. I understand that I am incorrectly doing this. That is where I am seeking help.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe.  I understand what you are saying.  I have been trying to figure out, how to add to the outside/global $request[] within the scope of the function.

Comment: Why would you need to add that into the function? Just return the result of the API call _from_ your function, and then add it to your array _outside_ of it. Your function should not need to get your results array passed as a parameter at all.

Comment: I have added the "batchUpdate" code, to my example code above, to show my think.  So to repeat, I wish to create $request[] array outside the function scope.....then add content to it within the function scope, then use batchUpdate outside the function scope to send the $request[] array  to the Google Slides API

Comment: Yes @CBroe, I have tried that as well, but then I cannot add to the global $requests array within the scope of the function, unless I use 'global $requests' in the function.................. function createNewSlide($slide_id) {
        $requests[] = new Google_Service_Slides_Request([
                'createSlide' => [
                'objectId' => $slide_id
                ]
        ]);
     return $requests;
   }

Comment: @AnuratChapanond yes what you state is key, and hence my issue.  How do I just return the object and not the array of array?

Comment: _“but then I cannot add to the global $requests array within the scope of the function”_ - but WHY do you want to do that? Makes no sense! Again: Have your function _return_ the object it creates, and add that return value to the array `$requests[] = createNewSlide($slide_id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing on from the comment,When you write `$requests[] =`, it means adding the result to an array. Then you return the resulting array. Since you want to return just the google object you don't have to pass $requests to the function and just return the google object from the function.

```
function createNewSlide($slide_id) {
    return new Google_Service_Slides_Request([
            'createSlide' => [
            'objectId' => $slide_id
            ]
    ]);
}
```

Then you can just add what returns from the function to $requests array.

```
$requests[] = createNewSlide($slide_id);
```

Comment: Thank you @AnuratChapanond.  Very simple and helpful.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you all that commented.  It guided and helped me to resolve my issue.